How to reverse a URL in format namespace:view:endpoint?
I have a Django project with the following urlpattern defined on project level:
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(('ws_shopify.urls', 'ws_shopify'), namespace='shopify')),
]

The file ws_shopify.urls defines the following urlpatterns:
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/shopify/', ShopifyWebhookAPIView.as_view(), name='webhook'),
]

The class ShopifyWebhookAPIView defines the following endpoint:
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ShopifyWebhookAPIView(APIView):
    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'], url_path='(?P<webshop_name>.+)/order_created', name='order-created')
    def order_created(self, request: Request, webshop_name=None):
        return Response({'message': f'Order created for {webshop_name}'})

My question is:
What is the correct name of this endpoint to be used in a test case using reverse()?
I am trying this now:
class WebhookTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_that_url_resolves(self):
        url = reverse('shopify:webhook:order-created', kwargs={'webshop_name': 'my-shop'})
        self.assertEqual(url, '/api/shopify/my-shop/order_created')

But this fails with the following error message:
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'webhook' is not a registered namespace inside 'shopify'

Not sure if it's relevant or not, this is how ws_shopify.apps looks like:
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ShopifyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'ws_shopify'


shopify:order-created?

Tried that as well,but it couldn't be found either.

I got it to work with the following changes:
In ws_shopify.urls:
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from ws_shopify.views import ShopifyWebhookViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ShopifyWebhookViewSet, basename='webhook')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/shopify/', include(router.urls)),
]

In ws_shopify.views:
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet

class ShopifyWebhookViewSet(ViewSet):
    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'], url_path='(?P<webshop_name>.+)/order_created', name='order-created')
    def order_created(self, request: Request, webshop_name=None):
        return Response({'message': f'Order created for {webshop_name}'})

In ws_shopify.tests_views:
class WebhookTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_that_url_resolves(self):
        url = reverse('shopify:webhook-order-created', kwargs={'webshop_name': 'my-shop'})
        self.assertEqual(url, '/api/shopify/my-shop/order_created/')

